# Is the imaginary part of $t\mapsto\zeta(1/2+it)$ close to the derivative of its real part?

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, l-functions

Plotting $t\mapsto\zeta(1/2+it)$ on Wolfram alpha, it seems that the maxima of its real part are close to the zeros of its imaginary part, while the maxima of the latter seem close to the inflection points of the former. Can this be made precise? For example, is there a canonical notion of distance between those two functions that attains only small values?

Comment: This can be rephrased as follows: the Hilbert transform of the real part is close to the derivative. Or, in yet another form: the Fourier transform of $t \mapsto \Re \zeta(1/2+i t)$ is concentrated around $\{-1, 0, 1\}$. This indeed is the case, and can be quantified in some sense; see, for example, [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/225409/108637).

Comment: Well, I should have rather written "this indeed *may* be the case, and *possibly could* be quantified". I do not claim I can quantify this at that moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(An extended comment.) The derivative of the real part does not really seem to be close to the imaginary part, as seen in the following picture generated by *Mathematica*:

[image: plot]

Code: `Plot[{Re[I Zeta'[1/2 + I t]], Im[Zeta[1/2 + I t]]}, {t, 0, 80}]`

The corresponding zeroes of the two functions indeed seem to be reasonably close to each other. This is no surprise, however: $\zeta(\tfrac{1}{2} + i t)$ essentially circles around (mostly in the right half-plane). In each "circle" the distance between a maximum or minimum of the real part and the corresponding zero of an imaginary part is roughly as large as the distance froth the "center" to the real axis. And most "circles" seem to be centered near the real axis.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Denoting respectively the derivative of the real part and the imaginary part by $Zr'$ and $Zi$, could one expect to get a result along the lines of $\int_{x_{0}}^{x}(Zr'(t)-Zi(t))dt\ll_{\varepsilon}x^{\varepsilon}$ for some $x_{0}>1$ and all $\varepsilon>0$?

Comment: I doubt this is any more regular than the integral of $\Im z(t)$, but honestly I know next to nothing about the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: Do you think my question in my previous comment should be asked separately?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: Again, I do not know, you may ask someone more knowledgeable.

Comment: There certainly does seem to be some sort of correlation: consider `ListPlot@Table[{Re[I Zeta'[1./2 + I t]], Im[Zeta[1./2 + I t]]}, {t, 0, 800}]` and `ListPlot@Table[{Re[I Zeta'[1./2 + I t]], Im[Zeta[1./2 + I t]]}, {t, 700, 800, 0.1}]`.